# Vim slowness when opening bashrc, and only bashrc

Tags: vim

I'm having a very strange problem with my Vim 7.4.488 installed via homebrew on OS X 10.10.5.

When I open my .bashrc, and *only* my .bashrc, Vim grinds to a halt and consumes 100% of a cpu core. While disabling all plugins and my .vimrc and this does eliminate the issue once it's running, it still takes >15 seconds to open the file.

My startuptime log is this (note the line about opening buffers):

```
000.005  000.005: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.067  000.062: Allocated generic buffers
000.307  000.240: locale set
000.323  000.016: GUI prepared
000.325  000.002: clipboard setup
000.331  000.006: window checked
000.725  000.394: inits 1
000.873  000.148: parsing arguments
004.464  003.591: expanding arguments
008.192  003.728: shell init
008.232  000.040: inits 2
014.032  005.800: init highlight
014.038  000.006: sourcing vimrc file(s)
014.051  000.013: inits 3
019.260  000.085  000.085: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/autoload/paste.vim
042.403  028.231  028.146: sourcing $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
079.517  037.235: starting GUI
117.769  038.252: GUI delay
117.774  000.005: setting raw mode
117.782  000.008: start termcap
117.815  000.033: clearing screen
18133.631  18015.816: opening buffers
18133.633  000.002: BufEnter autocommands
18133.637  000.004: editing files in windows
18133.667  000.030: VimEnter autocommands
18133.671  000.004: before starting main loop
18135.078  001.407: first screen update
18135.079  000.001: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

This was created using the command:

```
gvim -i NONE -u NONE --startuptime timeCost.txt -V12verbose.log ~/.bashrc
```

Anyone have a clue what's going wrong here or what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's embarrassing: turns out I had a line in my .bashrc that was 56 MB long... I have no idea how that happened. But that would certainly explain everything else dying. But honestly, who looks at the file size for their .bashrc when it's only 383 lines long?